# getPropertyValue sometimes returns empty string for CSS custom property

Tags: javascript, css, google-tag-manager, css-variables, getpropertyvalue

I am rendering the following style very early in the `<head>` :

```
<style>
:root {
    --enhanced: false;
}
@supports (selector(:not(.foo))) and
    (aspect-ratio: 1 / 1) and
    (margin-block-start: 1rem) and
    (gap: 1rem) and
    (display: grid) and
    (--css: variables) and
    (object-fit: cover) and
    (display: flex) {

    :root {
        --enhanced: true;
    }
}
</style>
```

Then, later, after Google Tag Manager has loaded on the page, I am then running some JavaScript to get the value of the CSS custom property that was declared:

```
var enhancedExperience = getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('html')).getPropertyValue('--enhanced');

return enhancedExperience;
```

I have deployed this code to a website with a very high amount of traffic to run an experiment. And I have found that roughly 16% of the time `getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('html')).getPropertyValue('--enhanced')` returns an empty string. And it is happening on a diverse range of browsers including the latest versions of all major browsers.

I was expecting the empty string for browsers that do not support CSS custom properties. But I can see from the analytics data that most of the 16% of users are on browser versions that do have support for CSS custom properties.

Why might this be? I thought perhaps race condition but considering the CSS custom property is declared so early on in the `<head>` and the JavaScript doesn't run until GTM is loaded, is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var enhancedExperience = window.getComputedStyle(document.body).getPropertyValue('--enhanced');
return enhancedExperience;
```